# How to listen Volume key events using Terminal?

Tags: android, terminal-emulator

I created as shell script for Android and I want to use Volume Keys to control or scroll info/selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Find-out-key-event-via-ADB?language=en_US
Like upper link .  you can use

```
adb getevent
```

```
adb sendevent
```

use getevent and then do your action , get the right action code ,  then , you can use adb sendevent **code that you get just now** to achieve your goal.